# How to make TextEdit open with most recent file by default?

Tags: textedit

Yes, I can see the list of recent files. I would like it to open the most recent file automagically. I don't see an option for this in TextEdit > Preferences.

Comment: Apparently not because my machine doesn't have a ~/Library/Saved Application State/ directory.

Comment: All Macs have that folder, one per user; it's hidden by default, but you can access it via Terminal, or by holding Opt as you open the View menu in Finder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextEdit will automatically re-open any documents that were open when you Quit it. (Assuming that this option in **System Settings > Desktop & Dock** is OFF, as shown.)

[image]

If you close a document, then TextEdit won't re-open it, unless you ask it to.

So if you want to keep working on it, don't close the document: just quit TextEdit.

I dare say it's possible to craft some sort of script that would query the list of recent files and open the first one -- but triggering that script is going to be at least as much effort as selecting the file from the list yourself.

To sum up: No.

Comment: How do I access this "Close windows when quitting an application" option?

Comment: @AlLelopath I've added the path. It's in System Settings > Desktop & Dock > Windows & Apps.

Comment: This is an older mac so its  Apple menu  > System Preferences, then click General.  
    Select “Close windows when quitting an app.”